# How to handle jw in H(jw)

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform

Apologies if this is a simple question, but it's been a second since I've used this material. If I have some equation $$ H(jw) = \frac{a-(jw)^2}{b-(jw)^2}$$ can I say that $$(jw)^2 = -w ?$$

Comment: $$(jw)^2 = -w^2 $$

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit (i.e. $j^2 = -1$)?